# How to prove that $(x^3-1)/(x-1)=1+x+x^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have doubts in this exercise to prove that $(x^3-1)/(x-1) = 1+x+x^2$
I try this method:
$(x-1)(x^2+x+1)/(x-1) = 1+x+x^2$
simplify
$x^2+x+1 = 1+x+x^2$
$0=0$

Can explain steps for resolution this problem?

Comment: Verifying that $(1 + x + x^2)(x - 1) = x^3 - 1$ is of course a good option, but if you don't already know (or can't guess) that the quotient ought to be $1 + x + x^2$, you may wish to look up [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should already know that
$$ (x-1)^3= x^3-3x^2+3x-1 $$ or
$$(x-1)^3=x^3-1-3x(x-1).$$
Adding $3x(x-1)$ to both sides gives
$$(x-1)^3+3x(x-1)=x^3-1$$
Taking $(x-1)$ as a factor on LHS gives
$$(x-1)[(x-1)^2+3x]=x^3-1.$$
Expand $(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$ to get
$$(x-1)(x^2-2x+1+3x)=x^3-1$$
$$(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=x^3-1$$
and divide both sides by $x-1$, provided that $x\ne 1$, to get
$$\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}=x^2+x+1$$
as desired.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).